# Hamiltonian Nuclear collective model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, angular-momentum, moment-of-inertia

Let $\mathscr{I}_3$ and $\mathscr{I}$ are the moments of inertia for rotations about symmetry axis 3 and about an axis perpendicular to it , and I is the angular momentum operator with components $I_1, I_2$  and $I_3$ along the body fixed axis(1,2,3), ,then 
,

> **How the Hamiltonian can be written  with angular momentum as**?
>   $$H= \sum_{i=1}^{3} \frac{\hbar ^2}{2\mathscr{I}_i}I_i^2=  \sum_{i=1}^{3} \frac{\hbar^2}{2J}(I^2 - I_3 ^2)+  \frac{\hbar}{2\mathscr{I}_3}I_3^2 $$

For the symmetric top $\mathscr{I}_1= \mathscr{I}_2 =\mathscr{I}$

---

**Source:** [Nuclear physics theory and experiment by RR Roy and BP NIGAM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0852267886)

In system 1 the body-fixed reference frame is attached to the rotating body. The 3-axis is used as the axis of symmetry. If $\mathscr I_3$ and $\mathscr I$ are the moments of inertia for rotations about about symmetry-axis 3 and about an axis perpendicular to it, and $\mathbf I$ is the total angular momentum operator with components $I_1$, $I_2$ and $I_3$ along the body-fixed axes, the Hamiltonian is given by
$$H=\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mathscr I_i}I_i^2
=\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mathscr I}(\mathbf I^2 - I_3 ^2)+\frac{\hbar}{2\mathscr{I}_3}I_3^2$$
where for the symmetric top $\mathscr I_1=\mathscr I_2=\mathscr I$.
[image: Figure]

---

### Consider

Let we denote the Euler angle of the spheroid by $(\theta,\phi, \psi)$.
Let's define some angular momentum operator, 
$$I^2 D^I_{MK}=I(I+1)D^I_{MK},$$
$$I_z D^I_{MK}=MD^I_{MK},$$
$$I_3 D^I_{MK}=KD^I_{MK}.$$
Considering these relations,

> **How can we write wave-function as $$\Psi^I_{MK}=|IMK\rangle=
>  \left[\frac{2I+1}{8 \pi^2}\right]^{1/2}D^I_{MK} (\theta, \phi,
> \psi)?\tag{1}$$ Here $(\theta, \phi, \psi)$ are the Euler angles.**

Now the spheroid symmetry,  rotations angle are 
$$\theta \rightarrow \pi+ \theta , $$$$\phi \rightarrow \pi- \phi,$$$$ \psi \rightarrow \psi.$$

Then how we can rewrite the equation (1)as,

$$\Psi^I_{MK}=|IMK\rangle=
 \left[\frac{2I+1}{8 \pi^2}\right]^{1/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+R_I)D^I_{MK} (\theta, \phi,
\psi)?\tag{2}$$ $$=
 \left[\frac{2I+1}{16 \pi^2}\right]^{1/2} \left[D^I_{MK} +(-1)^{I+K}D^I_{M,-K}\right]$$

Since, 
$$R_ID^I_{MK}(\theta, \phi,
\psi)=e^{i\pi (I+K)}D^I_{M,-K}(\theta, \phi,
\psi)$$
$$R_1^2 =1, R_1\Psi^I_{MK} = \Psi^I_{MK} $$

[The question is related to the rotational Hamiltonian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:ANUnuclearhonoursclass/Nuclear_Rotations)

Comment: The question has some errors in it. The first term in the final expression doesn't have units of angular momentum. The intermediate expression has units of angular momentum, but it equals a constant, so it can't be the Hamiltonian. Could you check the equation in whatever source you got it from and fix the errors?

Comment: I also don't understand the labels on the diagram in the figure. What are the two dashed arrows? Are they supposed to touch the tip of the solid arrow? What does the unlabeled solid arrow represent?

Comment: Sorry for the error, and the picture I got from " nuclear physics, Roy and Nigam"

Comment: I have edited now. can you check the question please?

Comment: The first expression, beginning with $H=\ldots$, doesn't really make sense. It has $\hbar$ in it, which would make it quantum-mechanical, but the $J_3$ term can only be classical, since a quantum rotor can't rotate around a symmetry axis. I still don't understand the redrawn version of the figure or the labels. I can't tell what's labeling what, what's perpendicular to what, whether the tips of the arrows are supposed to touch, or why some arrows are dashed.

Comment: Please see this book, page no 264, bks3.books.google.com.bd/books?id=7i9fcnMLZLQC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q=collective model&f=false

Comment: Hope the image is clear to you, I have cropped the pic from book and gave above the link.